# Co-ordinate geometry.

Tags: coordinate-systems

I have a straight line with it's start and end point coordinate. And I need to find center of arc with r radius and direction clockwise/ anti-clockwise according to requirement, making the line tangent to the arc(at end point of the line), such that only one center from possible should be picked.

[image]

Is it possible?

Program in java script or c# would be more fruitful to me.

Comment: Where are you having problems?

Comment: With given parameters I am not able to find the center of arc.(in coordinate)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the steps:

1. The initial coordinates of the line are $(x_1,y_1)$, the end of the line is at $(x_2,y_2)$, where the arc is tangent to the line. The radius of curvature is $R$. You need $(x_3,y_3)$, the center of the arc. You have two unknowns, so you need two equations.
2. Since $(x_2,y_2)$ is on the arc, it is at distance $R$ from the center. You can write this as $(x_2-x_3)^2+(y_2-y_3)^2=R^2$
3. The line from $(x_3,y_3)$ to $(x_2,y_2)$ is perpendicular to the line from $(x_2,y_2)$ to $(x_1,y_1)$, so the product of the slopes is $-1$. You can write this as
   $$\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}=-\frac{x_3-x_2}{y_3-y_2}$$
4. You square the last equation, and you can put $(y_2-y_3)^2$ into the first equation. You are left with a simple equation for $(x_2-x_3)^2=f(x_1,y_1,x_2,y_2,R)$. This obviously has two solutions, one for clockwise arc, one for counterclockwise arc.
5. Look up vector product on wikipedia to find out about clockwise/counterclockwise rotations. It will involve choosing one of $x_3=x_2\pm\sqrt{f(x_1,y_1,x_2,y_2,R)}$

Comment: Could you please explain how to choose the point according to given direction of arc (clockwise/ counterclockwise).

Comment: In 3D space, you create vectors $a=(x_2-x_1,y_2-y_1,0)$, $b=(x_3-x_2,y_3-y_2,0)$. The cross product $a\times b$ will be a vector either along $(0,0,1)$ or $(0,0,-1)$. When you write explicitly the formula for the cross product, all you need to do is to look at the last term (a function of $x_1,x_2,x_3,y_1,y_2,y_3$). If it's positive you have a counter clockwise arc. If it's negative the arc is in the clockwise direction. Make sure that you multiply them in the correct order, otherwise cross product will change sign